# delete a specific node in a grapgh adjacency list -directed graph

Tags: c, struct, graph, adjacency-list, adjacency-list-model

hi there I have this struct info

```
struct Node
{
  int dest, weight;
  struct Node *next;
};
```

I want to build a function that removes a specific node distance value
my main function for calling the delete function will look like this>>

```
int main()
{
       .
       .
       .
      struct Graph *graph;
      Node_delete(graph,x);

       .
       .
       .
}
```

[image]
if (x==4)
then the function will `delete` every `node` that contain the `distance` value of `4`
if the node in the middle of the previous node will be connected to the next node 
and if the node in the last node will be deleted and the previous node will point to `null` and so on...
so our graph result will look like this >>

[image]

any suggestions on how can I build the delete_node function?

Comment: int dest, weight; should be  int distance, weight;

Comment: @ravenspoint yes the variable name is 'dest' not 'destance', the image just to clarify!

Comment: Please fix your question so that the code matches the diagram.

Comment: Do you not notice your have spelled distance three different ways?

Comment: the struct `Node` just have two data variable `int dest` and `int weight` can you let me know what is not understood for you?!!@ravenspoint

Comment: The problem is not that I do not understand.  The problem is that you are inconsistent in your spelling and do not seem to realize what a bad fault that is for someone who hopes to become a coder.

Comment: You removed the diagrams a while ago — I'm not sure why.  The question is as clear as mud without them — it might be a bit clearer with them, though I'm not wholly convinced.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler check now

Answer (score 0):

```
LOOP L over head[]
   Step p through L
      IF "distance" ( however you decide to spell it ) = x
          IF this is first p of a l
              set head[] to p->next
          ELSE
              set previous next to current p->next
          delete p
```

Comment: If the first element has to be deleted you need to change the list

Comment: the first element will not be deleted will just point to null@ravenspoint

Comment: @Ôrel I guess you mean the first element of a node list.  In that case head[i] will be change to the next value in the deleted element.  Is it not obvious?

Comment: @Ôrel the head is an array of nodes, I just want to delete specific nodes in each linked list on the array, I will not delete any heads, see the images

Comment: @Ôrel I have tried your code https://onlinegdb.com/wcQGMxfiq   but it's not working can you check the issue?

Comment: No, it is not obvious, `set previous next to current next` there is no previous for first node.

Comment: @Ôrel OK I have edited my answer to spell out every little detail

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a global `graph` with your graph (as you don't have it as argument).

The function will return the number of deleted nodes.

You have to loop on all list with a simple `for`:

`for (int i = 0; i < graph.nodes; i++)`

Then, if the first element should be removed you need to change the `Node *` into the head array.
This is done with the `while` loop `while (first && first->distance == distance)`

Once you have delete the leading head, you can delete the other node with a `while (n->next)`

This will give something like:

```
static int Node_delete(Graph *graph, int distance) {
    int res = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < graph->nodes; i++) {
        Node *first = graph->head[i];
        Node *n = first;
        while (first && first->distance == distance) {
            first = first->next;
            free(n);
            res++;
            n = first;
        }
        while (n && n->next) {
            Node *next= n->next;
            if (next->distance == distance) {
                n->next = next->next;
                free(next);
                res++;
            }
            n = n->next;
        }
        graph->head[i] = first;
    }
    return res;
}
```

You will the full and the graph with elements removed

```
0 -> d: 2, w: 3 -> d: 2, w: 3 -> d: 4, w: 5 -> Null
1 -> d: 7, w: 6 -> d: 4, w: 6 -> d: 5, w: 4 -> Null
2 -> d: 2, w: 7 -> d: 2, w: 7 -> d: 8, w: 9 -> Null
3 -> d: 10, w: 13 -> d: 10, w: 13 -> d: 11, w: 7 -> Null
0 -> d: 2, w: 3 -> d: 2, w: 3 -> Null
1 -> d: 7, w: 6 -> d: 5, w: 4 -> Null
2 -> d: 2, w: 7 -> d: 2, w: 7 -> d: 8, w: 9 -> Null
3 -> d: 10, w: 13 -> d: 10, w: 13 -> d: 11, w: 7 -> Null
```

Full code with your schema, create, print and delete were done for test purpose:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef struct Node Node;

typedef struct Graph
{
  // An array of pointers to Node to represent an adjacency list
  size_t nodes;
  Node *head[];
} Graph;

// Data structure to store adjacency list nodes of the graph
struct Node
{
  int   distance;
  int   weight;
  Node *next;
};

static void graph_print(Graph *graph) {
    for (int i = 0; i < graph->nodes; i++) {
        printf("%d -> ", i);
        for (Node *n = graph->head[i]; n; n = n->next) {
            printf("d: %d, w: %d -> ", n->distance, n->weight);
        }
        printf("Null\n");
    }

}

static int Node_delete(Graph *graph, int distance) {
    int res = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < graph->nodes; i++) {
        Node *first = graph->head[i];
        Node *n = first;
        while (first && first->distance == distance) {
            first = first->next;
            free(n);
            res++;
            n = first;
        }
        while (n && n->next) {
            Node *next= n->next;
            if (next->distance == distance) {
                n->next = next->next;
                free(next);
                res++;
            }
            n = n->next;
        }
        graph->head[i] = first;
    }
    return res;
}

static Node* node_create(int distance, int weight, Node *next) {
    Node *n = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    n->distance = distance;
    n->weight = weight;
    n->next = next;
    return n;
}
static void node_delete(Node *n) {
    if (n) {
        node_delete(n->next);
        free(n);
    }
}
static Graph* graph_create(int nodes) {
    Graph *g = malloc(sizeof(size_t) + nodes * sizeof(Node));
    g->nodes = nodes;
    return g;
}

static void graph_delete(Graph *graph) {
    for (int i = 0; i < graph->nodes; i++) {
        node_delete(graph->head[i]);
    }
    free(graph);
}

int main(void)
{
    Graph *graph = graph_create(4);
    Node *n;

    n = node_create(4, 5, NULL);
    n = node_create(2, 3, n);
    n = node_create(2, 3, n);
    graph->head[0] = n;

    n = node_create(5, 4, NULL);
    n = node_create(4, 6, n);
    n = node_create(7, 6, n);
    graph->head[1] = n;

    n = node_create(8, 9, NULL);
    n = node_create(2, 7, n);
    n = node_create(2, 7, n);
    graph->head[2] = n;

    n = node_create(11, 7, NULL);
    n = node_create(10, 13, n);
    n = node_create(10, 13, n);
    graph->head[3] = n;

    graph_print(graph);
    Node_delete(graph, 4);
    graph_print(graph);
    graph_delete(graph);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: if the `graph` is exist in the main function under the variable name `struct Graph *graph;` then I will call from the main function `Node_delete(graph,x);` and the `Node_delete` function will receive `int Node_delete(struct Graph *graph,int distance)`

Comment: I have tried your code https://onlinegdb.com/wcQGMxfiq  but it's not working can you check the issue?

Comment: Can you provide the code to fill the graph and print it ?

Comment: yes you can view it here>>https://onlinegdb.com/y9FvitqMx

Comment: I mean a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I have fixed the code and added a full working code to test it